# Does influxDB have a limit to the number of databases you can have?

Tags: influxdb

Perf testing a tool.  We generate a bunch of metrics per test run.  But we want to keep each test run separate.  This seems like a db per run would allow us to do that, and at the same time allow us to give the tools we create to customers who would only have 1 install, and thus need only one db.  But we are talking hundreds of db's... granted they should be smaller as most would only be for a set of metrics covering a couple of hours.  But will influxdb limit us? or will performance suffer significantly?

Answer (score 1):

Looks memory/virtual memory appears to be the limiting factor.

On two 16gb boxes I added 500 db's with data on one, and 500 sets of data to the same db on the other.  The data was pretty small actually, the individual dbs were 440K after being loaded.

Memory use on the 500 db's was way higher.

500dbs    19.9g virtual, 3.3g resident
1db        2.5g virtual,  .9g resident

Comment: Could you please share more insights if you've made any further tests or actually implemented some multi-database setup?

Comment: They cut the whole team a few months later.  So this never got followed through on.